# How to validate only one field in a Flutter form?

Tags: flutter, forms

I have a form with several fields, at the end of the form there is a Login button which validates the whole form before submit.  Within the form there is a "Send Code" button which requires only the email address as mandatory field.  How can I just highlight the email address field without highlighting the password field when the Send Code button is pressed?
[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Email Address'),
                      controller: _EmailAddressController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter email';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Send Code',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              color: Colors.green[800],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Password'),
                  controller: _PasswordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter password';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Login',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
              ]
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you need to call [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldState/validate.html) method, and for getting a valid  `FormFieldState` use `GlobalKey`

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code
        
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Email Address'),
                        controller: _EmailAddressController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter email';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Send Code', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.green[800], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Password'),
                    controller: _PasswordController,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.grey[800], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: While the example code may or may not answer the question, you should elaborate on why it works and the general gist of what your solution is doing instead of dumping many lines of code with no explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `_EmailAddressController` has the text then validate for password.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Email Address'),
                      controller: _EmailAddressController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter email';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Send Code',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              color: Colors.green[800],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Password'),
                  controller: _PasswordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (!_EmailAddressController.text.isEmpty && (value == null || value.isEmpty)) {//You can also add condition for valid email.
                      return 'Please enter password';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Login',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
              ]
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```